# How to adjust letter-spacing in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx-2, letter-spacing

When using JavaFX2, how can i adjust the letter-spacing between characters of a Text object?

Examples either in code or css are welcome.

Comment: I've tried to find a css property for this or a method on the Font or Text classes.

Comment: Nothing exists in the public documentation for the [JavaFX 2 Text](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html)  - neither in the proposed [Java 8 TextFlow](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html).  Check the [issue tracker](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) and create a new feature request if needed.

Comment: I created https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36099 to request this feature. Please up vote it if you would like this feature to be added to JavaFX.

Comment: I ended up putting spaces between characters.