# How to adjust character spacing in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How does one do the following change to a `javafx.scene.text.Text` object (shown in the picture)?
The ***character* spacing** of the second line is increased.
Notice that I am not asking for ***line* spacing**. The class already has this property.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133256/how-to-adjust-letter-spacing-in-javafx) doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: See also [*How to adjust letter-spacing in JavaFX*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15133256/230513)

Comment: Guess you have to use some hack like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220679/how-to-set-the-letter-spacing-aka-tracking-of-a-font-in-javafx)